# Should I list an on-call job where I barely ever work?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I've been working at a company on-call overnights for about 6 months now, of which I've only *actually* worked with them for 3 months, and during those months only worked less than a week. I'd estimate that my overall experience here is only about 50 hours total.

Since the economy has been slow and they don't need me near as often, I'm considering the usefulness of even listing that I work there on my resume. I'm technically still employed there and on their payroll, so I've been listing it as working 0 hours per week, just to have it there.

Is there any reason to list this job at all, or should I only even mention it to people if they specifically ask for it (like list all your employment in the past *n* years)? If so, how little is too little for a job to be worthy of appearing on a resume?

Comment: Is this on-call job the only one you have or do you have something else concurrently?

Comment: Currently, yes. Though I did hold a temporary job during it and am starting another temporary one soon.

Comment: I believe you could still add it. Word it in such a way that it does not show up as a significant part of your work experience, but you are able to highlight your skills (technical or otherwise). You can showcase this as having a certain type of experience and/or skills but having actually used them for a small duration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-it-ok-to-leave-very-short-term-employment-off-my-resume)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is not your primary position, and there is nothing to be gained by adding it, there's no reason to add it to your resume proper. You will still need to disclose it on any application you fill out that asks you about "n previous positions".

However, if it is a position that fills a gap on your resume of some length (e.g. 2-3 months),  then add it as whatever title you hold there -- if it is "On-call Developer" or "Developer", or whatever.  You don't have to go into any detail about how much you worked or when; the goal of this entry is to show that you didn't have a gap, not that you did great things (unless you did, in which case by all means talk about them).

If I'm reviewing your resume and I read that it's not a full-time job (or for that matter isn't a job you've held for very long), I'm not expecting to learn anything from it besides someone invested time in you and you didn't get fired.  In other words, not much.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  A resume is the time for the author ( of the resume ) to highlight their character, skills, experiences and as long as what is written is the truth anything that adds no value should be left out.  Of course on any formal paper work it should be listed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what accomplishments or achievements you reached while at the on-call job. If it won't strengthen your resume, then it should be minimized.

You are absolutely correct about disclosing any previous positions, but allow them to make that request. If you are currently employed there, you may have to disclose that to a company that makes an offer.

Answer (score 0):

You could spin it in a positive fashion. The fact that you were "dedicated" enough and "flexible" enough to be on call for night times shows a level of commitment and preparedness to work that employers would like. Compare that to someone with "family baggage" where they are unable to help outside of office hours.

Just brush aside the number of hours worked and focus on how you were prepared to help them out at nights at the drop of a hat. Even make up or tell them the truth about how you prepared for that. Did you sleep or were awake all the time?, if asleep did you have relevant materials to hand and a booted machine ready to instantly help out?. Describe (and elaborate if required) the instances you were called up and how you were "instantly" able to help and offered a great service.