# Termination during probation period

Tags: work-experience, relieving-letter, probation

I have been terminated during my probation period (after having served 2 months out of the 3 months of probation). Does the probation period experience add value to a resume? The job entailed me getting into a completely new role (writing) from a s/w techie role. I joined this firm after 4 months of quitting my previous role.

However, the relieving letter I received states that I left on my own accord.

Should I be adding this work into my resume, as my resume would carry a big gap if I do not show some experience. Moreover, the role from which I am terminated is not related to the positions I will be applying in future. What information should I include in my resume in this case. I continue to have interests in the same writing field. Can I ask my current employer to issue me experience certificate, considering the fact that the probation was for 3 months?

Please suggest whether it'd be right to show this experience. Also, should I get in touch with this employer and ask whether they'd attest the same to my future employers that they've written (i.e. Of having resigned on my own rather than a termination)

Comment: You use the terms "experience certificate" and "relieving letter" -- are you in India (or another non-US location)?  Please indicate if so, because I suspect the answers will be different outside of the US.

Comment: Double-posting is not cool, -1.  Your other post with this same question is http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27523

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-it-ok-to-leave-very-short-term-employment-off-my-resume)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, before anything you need to face the solid realities: This gig was 2 months & they do not want you there. They could be right, they could be wrong. But in general, this is not good.

Fair warning, but the reality is the past 6 months need to just disappear from your resume. But that said, here are the specifics:

> Does the probation period experience add value to a resume?

Nope. Never. Showing you worked for somewhere for less than 6 months only has value in an internship.

> I am into this new company for 2 months and apparently they are
>   displeased with my performance.

That is not good. Essentially those 2 months are gone from your employment history.

> Can I ask my current employer to issue me experience certificate,
>   considering the fact that the probation was for 3 months?

If they are displeased at your performance do you think that they will give you a piece of paper saying, “Hey, this former employee is great!”

Now there is good news:

> So, discontinuing services would mean that my resume reflects a 6-month gap…

This is not bad. A 6 month gap can just mean you took time off to do anything other than work. Which is acceptable. Do you have a hobby? Tell them you took 6 months off to pursue personal things like a hobby.

But adding to your resume that you worked at one place for 4 months then quit & then went onto another place where you didn’t even make it past the 3 month probation will not help you out at all ever.

I would just leave the gap & not even mention the 2 gigs that did not work out. Anything where you indicate you lasted less than a year at two gigs will never look good under any circumstance.

Also a postscript, but basically you might want to also step back to under stand why you quit one job after 4 months & then shifted into another job where you took on a new role yet are being terminated after 2 months. Learn from both of these experiences so your next gig is one you can thrive in.

Comment: I don’t know what exactly @learning_fly means by “experience certificate”. But, even if the company is not happy with his job, he can ask the company for a certificate saying that he worked *there*, in *this* role, and from *this date* to *that date*. And the company will probably give him such a certificate. In some countries, this has legal and financial implications.

Answer (score 9):

One word of caution: it's very risky to be not fully honest during an interview. If you claim to have "pursued a personal interest" and then I would find out later that you were actually employed, I would fire you right away and also put you on the "do not hire" list. Mistakes and problems are negotiable, lying and dishonesty are not.

I think it's okay to not put these experiences in your resume, but if you get a direct question, I would recommend to fess up.

Another point that seems to be blatantly missing here: You need to talk to your current employer to find out why they are not happy with you and what you can do to fix it. Even if you hate the job, it would be far better to stick it through, make sure you don't get terminated and then start looking for alternatives while you are still employed. Being able to work through a difficult situation like this could be a real asset for any future interviews.

Comment: Although Hilmar's reaction would be harsh, I agree that it's better not to lie in this situation. Many reasons can lead to the lie being discovered, and then trust would be broken. If @learning_fly is asked, the best s/he can do is telling the truth in a positive light. Focusing on what s/he has learnt from the failure. One progresses more from one's failures than from one's successes.

Comment: Not sure why the other response was accepted. Best is to: (1) Think hard about reasons why you failed twice, and learn lesson from it. (2) Find job where this will not repeat, and explain your new employer why this time it will be different.

Comment: +1 for addressing the situation without completely brushing this stint under the rug. Also agree that it's very important to understand why you were fired, particularly since you're interested in staying in the same field.

Comment: Can any one help me here, I am in the same shoe as the OP, but I actually quit after two months because I was being de-skilled. what advice do you have for me?