# What to include on a resume regarding temporary work?

Tags: resume

I wonder how I should include a temporary assignment that did not go well.   It was for a 3 month contract but it was ended early by the employer.   Should I include this on my resume or should I leave it off.   I have been otherwise unemployed since the end of 2013.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey Michael, is this the same as [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/)? Do you mean 'temporary' as in you were a temp at a company for 3 months before moving on to a different company as a temp? Or that you were in a job for 3 months which was short, so you're calling it temporary? An [edit] may help clear up the question. Thanks in advance!