# Gap in my career ( less than 2 months)

Tags: career-development, careers, employment-gaps

After getting my degree, I have joined in a software company and worked for 1.6 years. After getting an offer (a small and start-up company) in another company, I moved over there and worked for 6 months.

Due to certain reasons I quit my job. Overall gap up to now is less than 2 months and I want to continue as developer somewhere and my previous company willing to give me experience until I get another job.

I have few questions:

1. My previous company didn't issue any pay slips and i cant even show my bank statement because of last 2 months gap?
2. How to manage with payslips and bank statements in background verification?
3. If I need to specify gap, how can I keep that in resume?
4. How should I answer the question "what is the reason to change company for just six months"?

Comment: [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9965/25792)

Answer (score 2):

> How should I answer the question "what is the reason to change company
>   for just six months"?

You should answer with the real reason why you quit after just 6 months.

Here you said "Due to certain reasons I quit my job". Obviously, that's a poor answer for an interview, so you are going to have to come up with something better.

My advice is usually to be honest. Simply tell them the reason you quit.

If the reason is something a hiring manager might be concerned about, then make sure you tell them why it won't happen again, and why you'll be staying with your next company for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest concern is with one of your sub questions:

> How to manage with payslips and bank statements in background
>   verification?

That implies that you were prepare to lie as part of the background investigation. That is both the quickest way to lose a job and the longest lasting way to lose a job.

Manufacturing proof would be a big red flag to a potential employer. The lie is also long lasting because if years later they found out you faked the proof, they would have reason to consider you untrustworthy.

The answer to you 3 other questions is simple. Tell the truth. You had a job, and you quit without having a new job.  You will have to tell them the reason, otherwise your quitting seems rash. Of course being rash is not a job skill they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks mhoran_psprep and i will try to tell the reason by avoiding all these fake slips etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you live, and maybe the situation is different there. But speaking from a U.S. perspective:

One: Having a short gap -- a few months -- in your job history is not a big deal. Employers know that people sometimes lose or quit a job and don't necessarily get a new job immediately. If the gap drags out into six months or a year, then it becomes more of a problem. Employers start to wonder if there is a good reason why you can't get a job, or if you are lazy and didn't want to work.

Two: I have never had a potential employer ask for pay slips or any other proof of previous employment. But if that's common where you live, as others have said, I definitely would not lie about it and try to fake it. Ethical considerations aside, if you are caught in a lie in an interview, you are very unlikely to be hired. And if after you are hired they find out you lied during the interview, that is often grounds for being immediately fired. Lying during the interview means that you will spend your entire time with that company in fear that they'll find out. Don't do it.

Three: You don't have to tell us on this forum why you quit your last job, but an employer will expect something more than "for certain reasons". Frankly, I think that refusing to say why you quit would be the absolute worst possible answer. If I was the interviewer, I would take it for granted that if you had a good reason, you would have told me, so it must be a bad reason. And then I will imagine the worst possible reasons. Unless your reason is really bad, like you were caught stealing from the company or you beat up the boss, you are better off to tell the real reason. You may be able to paint it in a way that makes it sound okay or at least not so bad. Again, don't lie about it, but you can present things in a way favorable to yourself. If there's no way to make it sound good, then say, "Yes, I made a stupid mistake doing that and I will never do that again." Most companies are happy to have someone who learns from his mistakes. What they don't want is someone who makes the same mistakes over and over.