# under-1-year experiences in different industries - Explanation/Support for Strengths

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, hiring-process, layoff

I was an international student studying for Accounting in Canada and decided to stay while working. I am in my 20's (but faced no real age-discrimination)

1. first position: small biz. Business/Tax Consultant, clerical position for 10 months - resigned
2. **second position: mid biz (energy). Accounting Clerk, entry position for 16 months.** (strongest experience) - contract ended

This was a mat-leave cover contract and went well - they offered a bit of extension for me to stay while re-training during while the team shuffled positions.

3. third position: corporation, but store-level. Store Admin/Accountant for 5 months. It was part-time/temporary. (no strong references here) - resigned
4. fourth position: multinational corp (tour industry). Accounts Receivable Analyst for 7 months. Hectic changes in company, my role was caught in the middle and I was laid off (with little notice)

I was incredibly overworked at the most recent, 4th position with very loose company structure (I spent most of the time on process improvement across departments while my own boss didn't really care or understand the shortage of resources/time). It did not end well but I have a number of coworkers (senior Financial Analyst, Sales Manager) who appreciated my hard work and support.

My resume shows "job-hopping" which makes me look disloyal but I was diligent at all times (perhaps too much) and learned to adapt to different environments. It's true that I had less exposure to my direct manager while I worked closely with coworkers (often in different departments) and that often caused misunderstandings - which I understand I should be on top of and improve on.

In future interviews how do I convey the message that I am diligent and adaptable in spite of the impression job hopping leaves?

Also I would like to ask for other advices/cautions on my next job hunt which is ongoing at the moment.

Edit: found similar post, but I am seeking advice given my latest "lay-off" status

> [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-it-ok-to-leave-very-short-term-employment-off-my-resume)

Answer (score 2):

1. Usually your resume doesn't need to be written in a pre-determined format.
2. Your resume tells your story. Keep in mind the kind of story do you want to be associated with.
3. Some light research in this kind of career, seems to point to a resume oriented to skills, instead of to positions. Instead of listing your positions and for each position the skills you demonstrated in it, you could list your skills,and for each skill the positions in which you developed it.