# Would adding a role to my LinkedIn profile I spent a short amount of time doing negatively effect me?

Tags: internship, work-experience, linkedin

I'm currently doing a work placement as part of my university degree and have had the oppertunity to move to a variety of teams. I have previously work in two different roles, one for 5 months and another for 6 months. I've now moved onto a final team for the last month of my placement. I've learnt some useful skills so far in this team but I wouldn't say that I have had enough time to properly understand all of the job roles. I would like to add this experience to my LinkedIn profile but feel that a future employee might see this useless experience due to the limited amount of time spent in the team.

Could this negatively effect me in any way or is any experience good experience?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I'm not moving to a different company, just a different role.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-it-ok-to-leave-very-short-term-employment-off-my-resume

Comment: @MarvMills Hi Marv. That does cover some of the points, but that questions seems to be targetted to moving to a completely new company. This is within the same company, just a seperate role.

Comment: Couldn't you list this as one post rather than 3 different entries (5 months + 6 months + 1 month is just too much detail). You can explain in the details section of the whole one-year post (for example, "during this post I filled the roles of X, Y and Z, doing tasks a, b and c. My time was divided 45-45-10 between roles X, Y and Z.")

Comment: Did your job title change within those three internal roles?  If the answer is no, then your job didn't technically change.  One entry is fine :)

Answer (score 4):

You worked for one company and did *x* different things.   Unless you worked for teams that are widely known throughout your industry (e.g. the Gmail team or the XBox team), the fact that you did those things for different teams is probably only relevant to people within the company.

I would list the company and then list the different types of work that you performed... simple as that.  There's no need to mention the individual teams if you don't have a really good reason for doing so.