# Date Discrepancy on CV

Tags: resume, hiring-process, references, hiring

long time lurker first time poster.

So, I left a job to start a new one but I got sacked and never made it through my probation.  To appease the job centre I applied for a job I didn't think I'd get. I thought I'd be too expensive.

To cut a long story short I got offered this new job.  But when I applied I sent in the wrong CV which didn't have the job I was sacked from listed.  I'd brushed over it with 'freelance' work on a new version of it but sent the old one.

Anyhoo...they've sent me a starter pack with a reference sheet in it.  On the sheet it says start and end dates.  Should I put the true end date on it? The person I'm returning it to has never spoken to me.

Will she have a copy of my CV to cross reference the dates with or will she just look at what I've written down on the form and correlate it with my ex boss?

It's a 3 month discrepancy.

Comment: Honestly, at the end of the day, I would say that this is a personal decision (especially with such a short window of three months), but if you choose not to send in the correct resume, I would just maintain consistency on the reference sheet with the resume I *had* submitted.

Comment: Are they asking you to list all your previous jobs for a background check? are they asking if you have ever been fired?

Comment: They're asking for my most recent employer to be my main reference so they think it's the job I had before the one I was fired from.  Basically the job I was fired from isn't listed on my CV. I was there 8-9 weeks before I got the chop.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the person phoning for a reference will have my CV in front of her or will she just have the reference form and go off the dates from that?

Answer (score 2):

So you got the job with an older CV.

Omitting a job from your CV is fine, but [caveats apply](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9967/9549); perhaps not fully in your case as it sounds like you've already got the job.

A common interview question is *have you ever been fired*, I don't think you were asked that or you would've mentioned it here. Lying to *that* question would up the stakes considerably.

If you are found out you can downplay the omission:

> Job *X* wasn't a good fit and I didn't stay there long to make a significant contribution, and I wanted to focus on those jobs that I did.

You can even play stupid if the wording of the request allows you:

> I thought you wanted dates for the jobs I listed on my CV only!

In any case you've made your decision. If you include the dates now, you might have to account for the discrepancy; ultimately, it's not something we can answer for you. You must assume that person has a copy of the CV you sent in.

Comment: Yeah it was a CV that was slightly out of date and it says I'm still at the job I had before I got the chop.  Would it be ok to put the actual date I finished that job on the reference form?

Comment: The first option here (the not "playing stupid" one) is probably the one I would choose. Just own up is almost always the right answer. "There was a mistake, but as I wasn't there long, I didn't have time to make any sort of impact and didn't think that it added anything useful to it." and be prepared to answer questions about what you did and why you left. Answer as clearly as possible.

Comment: I just don't want the offer rescind because of it.