# As a job-hunting director/VP candidate, list current temp work?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, job-search

I’ve been job hunting for 7 months as a Director/VP candidate (former management consultant). For fun and extra cash, I have taken a temp job at a national, speciality retailer. I enjoy it but omit the job from my resume, as it may look unbecoming. Should I mention it in interviews? Will it show up in a background check?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9965) What's the alternative? Lying and saying you've been unemployed for the last 7 months will almost certainly be worse. What kind of temp work? Are we talking something along the level of a teller, or more of a well-paid qualified contractor?

Comment: Which industry? Why are you holding out for a director/VP job?

Comment: I have been a VP / Director for several years in corporate settings. I wasn’t able to find contract work in my field (business strategy). I am looking for a job at a similar level to my previous job. Meanwhile, the retail work is fun. I only wonder whether it will reflect poorly in me. Part of me also wonders, if it reflects poorly on me, do I want to be working for such a person.

Answer (score 5):

no don't add it. unless it is relevant to what you're applying for.

where relevant - > same skill sets used. I can't imagine how it could ever be relevant though.

won't show up in back ground checks no.

Just say you worked on a start up idea or an ico in the mean time, or that you travelled.