# Explain in interview being fired twice in short interval?

Tags: termination, performance

I got fired today from a company I joined about 3 months ago. Before that I was fired from another company after joining them for 2 months. Both positions were as a Software Engineer and from both it was due to not adequate performance. There were not specific quantifiable targets in any of the cases and most feedback was verbal and a bit wishy-washy. Also worth noting that in both cases there was a big absence of the team to ask things which made things a bit harder.

From the first company I indeed had a pretty slow start due to being uncomfortable with the hardware and due to new things to me. There wasn't much for me to do about that but I learned my lesson I think (going the extra mile in the very beginning and showing pro-activity).

At my second job I was told that they had some seniority concerns after 1 month. This was due to a mishap from my point of view - asking me to suddenly switch to a new project and finish it by the end of the week. It was decided for me to switch to a 3rd project to work a while while my work is being reviewed. From this point I think I did pretty good. I managed to get enough code out (3 PRs in 1 week for the tech-savvy). Then there was the Christmas holidays and after that 1 week of off-site work where not much work was involved. On the trip I got sick and then when I finally did get back to work, I managed again to make good progress (getting PRs out, etc.). Unfortunately the day after that was a 1-2-1 meeting that had been pre-scheduled ahead of time and that's where I was fired.

I did mention my progress. The feedback was that the code was not of senior quality which I find weird to hear. Namely since the code was reviewed and only minor changes were requested and some optimizations.

In any case I feel a bit devastated now since I don't know how to go about all this when looking for a new job. I'm pretty sure no employer will feel comfortable hiring someone who was let go so shortly twice due to poor performance..

1. Do I scrap these 2 jobs from my CV? Before all this I have a gap of 3 months and then 1 year of a permanent position where my position became redundant.
2. What to tell during a screening or an interview about my last 2 positions?

Comment: [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9965)

Answer (score 4):

> Do I scrap these 2 jobs from my CV? Before all this I have a gap of 3
>   months and then 1 year of a permanent position where my position
>   became redundant.

You could, but you risk it being discovered if the company you apply to does a background check.  If they do, you will have some explaining to do and most likely won't get the job.  My general recommendation is **do not lie**.

> What to tell during a screening or an interview about my last 2
>   positions?

Your best bet is to **tell the truth**.  Be honest about what happened, but be as concise as possible and redirect any such talk back to how you would be great for the position you are interviewing for.

I would suggest that whatever job you do get next, *you suck it up and stick with it for awhile* to help build up your work history.

Good luck.