# What's my best play if there's any issue on my background check with contacting my latest employer?

Tags: job-offer, background-check

I was working at my most recent employer until May 21st 2018 (2 week notice given). Applied for a position at another company(a company I've REALLY been wanting to work for in the past 5 years but had a hard time getting an interview there) about a month before (early April) I left my most recent. I was interviewed for that company on May 11th.

In the interim of all this, I was planning a move from my most recent employer to a consulting company. Turns out, it's not a great fit for me. The reasons are neither here nor there.

Even though I was planning on joining the consulting company when I left my most recent employer in May 21st, I kept the interview with the other company because I wanted to keep my options open in case the consulting gig didn't work out and honestly because I really want to work for this other company. And I also kept it because I know from experience that this sector moves very slowly. Recall the fact that I applied in early April and I was offered the position on June 11th. So 60 days.

I just filled out the background check release authorization forms online and during this, there was an option to select "okay to contact most recent employer for verification purposes" or something.

The problem is, my most recent employer is obviously not what is on my resume right now. But I obviously was still employed AT that employer when I applied/interviewed. So let's say they call the most recent employer on my resume which is listed as "May 2017 - Current" and they say "oh he left on May 21st". What is my play here? Cause obviously I'm in a new position that I probably won't even be in for 4 weeks. Do I just be honest and describe the situation?

"Well, I was employed at company XYZ when I applied for the position and interviewed but left them shortly after to explore something new, so my resume at the time of application submission was current and relevant. I am currently employed by a consulting firm that I have no obligations to and was planning on leaving to accept this position."

How much honesty is necessary? Is it even worth talking about my current role (I'm thinking about the "rule" where you don't even put a company on your resume if you were there for only 2-4 weeks)? Would it just be better to say I left in anticipation of this new job because the commute was killing me?

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9965)

Answer (score 2):

I would update your information to reflect the start and end dates.  I work for a financial institution and when my background check was initiated I had a background specialist call me and drill me on a past employment.  My past employer was company ABC, but I was hired thru a temporary staffing agency.  Well, I failed to place the temporary staffing agency as my employer as technically they were.  In my interrogation, at least that's what it felt like, from the background specialist we finally cleared up where I made the error.  Luckily it was an honest mistake, but that's not what the specialist thought at first.  He thought I was trying to hide a past employment.  So that being said, I would list the last employers information.  Just to cover your self.  I hope this helps?  Good luck.

Comment: It's a big mistake to put the customer of a staffing agency as your employer rather than the staffing agency.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say honesty is always the best choice - especially in this case where the potential new job wants to do a background check, which implies that they want to know that they can trust you. It wouldn't take much time to update your résumé to add the most current job.

It seems to me like you had a temporary deviation from your usual path rather than making the job-hopping a pattern, and that will be evident in your résumé to anyone who takes a serious look at it.

Also, you might enjoy the "[Stats About Job Hopping to Help You Decide: To Hop or Not to Hop?](https://www.flexjobs.com/blog/post/stats-about-job-hopping/)" article on the FlexJobs site or, if you're really hard-core into research, the "[Welcome to 100 Days on Jobs for Career Changers!](https://www.flexjobs.com/blog/post/welcome-100-days-on-jobs-for-career-changers/)" article has 100 pages that you can use to really dig into the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to your excuse/reason is in your question:

> Recall the fact that I applied in early April and I was offered the position on June 11th. So 60 days.

**It's totally normal for things to change in a 60 day period.** Your resume was correct as of the time you applied (at least that's how I'm interpreting things). That was 60 days ago. In that time, things have changed.

**Update the resume to show your exit date from that employer, and explain during the background check process that your resume from April is out of date.** No reason to elaborate unless asked, and at that point, default back to "standard practice" in terms of how to answer questions about short term employment, reasons for leaving, etc.