# Discovered that my new job has cameras in the restrooms

Tags: united-states, unprofessional-behavior, privacy

Location is Washington state, USA.

I've been at this company for less than a week and I hardly know everyone yet. I had to go to IT today to get some stuff set up and the sysadmin had all the security cameras in a 4x4 grid on a TV. While he was working on my laptop, I noticed that two cameras show the mens and womens restrooms. They're on the ceiling overlooking the stalls so you can see into them. I didn't say anything about them at the time because I'm not sure what to do. I went back and found the camera in the mens' room, it's inside an air vent so it's very hard to notice, while none of the other cameras outside are hidden.

I'm not sure if this is known by the whole company and it's just accepted, or if it's legal at all. I'm definitely not going to work for a company that does this. I'm trying to decide if I should:

1. Go to the sysadmin and ask him about it.
2. Go to my manager and tell him, in case these aren't actually approved.
3. Leave the company. I'm not worried about finding another job, and if I did this I'd email my whole department and let them know, then walk out.
4. Alert some legal authority.

Does anyone have any advice for the best way to handle this?

Comment: This probably isn't a major factor in what you should do, but are the bathroom cameras clearly visible to people actually in the bathrooms? If they are concealed, that's another layer of concern.

Comment: Please do report back on what you decided to do and what happened!

Comment: The real fishy thing here is NOT that there are video cameras in the rest-rooms (let's just assume that they could be acceptable from some POV). The real fishy thing is that THEY ARE CONCEALED. That leads me to think that they (whoever) know that it is illegal to have them, and they do not want people to know about it. If the cameras would be legal / acceptable / whatever, they would be visible just like any other cameras.

Comment: Where is OP I need to know what happened !!!

Answer (score 70):

> They're on the ceiling overlooking the stalls so you can see into
>   them.

So they're overlooking the stalls even when the stalls are closed?

The law in Washington seems pretty clear-cut to me.

https://www.washemploymentlaw.com/employee-rights/workplace-surveillance#1

I would call the police. Don't call 911. It's not an emergency. But find out what the local number for the police is and call them. If you're not sure about calling them, you could just visit your local police station and describe what you saw.

Do not ask the manager. Do not talk to HR. Get the police involved. If you complain about the cameras before the police get there, the cameras will be moved, pointed into different directions, incriminating footage will get erased, and signs notifying you of that hidden camera in the vents will be posted everywhere. In fact, that camera in the vents may even disappear overnight, so discreetly double-check that it is still there tomorrow morning before telling the police to come.

Then, I would use that police report when filing for unemployment (since as you said, you're not interested in working for such an employer). That being said, if upper management was truly not aware, they may beg you to stay.

Comment: "`In fact, that camera in the vents may even disappear overnight`" - they might, if the operators noticed the OP examining them. But, if he checks, they might notice that too ...

Comment: I would suggest trying to make a picture of the camera from the stall. Even better would be a picture of the screen showing the footage. This would at least give OP the possibility to show evidence in case of a cover up. I really do hope that if this is really happening the police will get them for that as this is wrong on many levels.

Comment: "That being said, if upper management was truly not aware, they may beg you to stay." Not if you are going to the police first. Upper management would rather deal with it themselves first, which may actually involve dragging the culprits to the police, but having a police raid in the company is in most cases a career ending move.

Comment: @Hilmar the police wouldn't necessarily have to divulge which employee called them, would they? In that case, it might be best to not do anything that would draw unnecessary attention (such as photographing the cameras). Perhaps best to contact a lawyer first.

Comment: @KamiKaze Absolutely don't try to take pictures or check they are still there in a noticeable way. Don't even look at it. At the latest after the police comes, you should assume (worst case) someone still has a copy of the footage and goes through it trying to find out who discovered the cameras. And even if you want to quit anyway, it's still better if you can do it without any hassle, on your own terms.

Comment: @Nobody Well as OP wants to quit anyway, they should not be concerned by this. And OP already did it, so getting evidence for the claims, before it might be removed and leaving them empty handed with a "false claim" should be a better course of action to my mind.

Comment: It's OK to call 911 as this is a crime "in progress". 911 call centers are equipped to handle critical, time-sensitive stuff and, if needed, can transfer you to the appropriate department (but don't call at midnight on a Friday night!). Also 911 calls are always logged and the records are kept.

Answer (score 29):

You need to consult a lawyer and then the police.  While I am not a lawyer, a quick Google search would ***HIGHLY*** indicate this is illegal.  Putting a camera in a bathroom violates a person's reasonable expectation of privacy.  Read this [article](https://rhodeslegalgroup.com/video-taping-another-person-in-washington/) from a lawyer in Washington state for more information.

Its probable one or more persons will be facing fines, criminal charges, civil charges, and jail/prison time. A lawyer will advise you on how best to protect yourself and coworkers when reporting this to the police. Not to mention advise you on what could happen in the future. This is serious. Even not reporting it could be unethical, or even illegal.

Comment: @RichardU I would hope its obvious, but perhaps not.  Its probable one or more persons will be facing fines, criminal charges, civil charges, and jail/prison time.  A lawyer will advise you on how best to protect yourself and coworkers when reporting this to the police.   Not to mention advise you on what could happen in the future.  This is serious.  Even not reporting it could be unethical, or even illegal.

Comment: I agree that contacting a lawyer first is probably the best and safest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Management, HR and sysadmin are definitely poor choices to start.

I'm not from the U.S. and I don't know in which field it is, but if you feel uncomfortable going directly to the police, talking to a union representative in the company is surely a good option. They might know if a similar issue has been raised and already addressed in the past and, in case not, raise it in the cleanest way.

If that does not work, due to lacking of union representative or to an unhelpful one, the police is the next option, and other answers have surely addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

Cameras pointed *into* bathrooms stalls is extreme prison-like surveillance. Utterly unacceptable in every imaginable workplace, let alone the USA. Most likely it's a creep Sysadmin and not any sane manager's idea of a policy.

The police definitely need to be called at some point. But it might be helpful to gather several employees including higher level ones, bring them into the bathroom and pull down the vent to expose the camera, and then take a walk to the IT guy's office.

Yes, it would be a disruptive scene. The plus side is that it avoids putting you in a situation where the camera is removed making you look like you're making an explosive unbelievable claim.

Answer (score -26):

Inform your manager and move forwards from the response. This is illegal most workplaces unless perhaps there is full disclosure or it's some sort of porn business perhaps.

But you cannot ignore it now, you're on camera peering into mensroom air vents.

In terms of your options stated.

1) No, this isn't your role and you need to have your back covered.

2) Yes

3) No idea what you think this would accomplish particularly since you have only a little information.

4) Not until you have spoken to your manager and got at least some info.

**Why not call police? Several reasons:**

You have little info, these cameras might be a prank or something in bad taste but not what they seem.

Cameras could be removed before anyone looks.

You'll be unemployed and kicking over a fire at the same time, you will make personal enemies out of strangers, never a good thing.

Leaving a job under a cloud so quickly isn't great on a resume.... you can say it was cameras in the loos, but realistically, how believable is that?

Comment: Leaving a job after one week isn't great on a resume. That's true enough. But if you've only been there one week, you should leave it off your resume entirely (unless it's for a security clearance, which I doubt).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk by then you may be famous in the industry as the 'Seven Day Toilet Adventurer' either way the company hierarchy should be the first go to, not the police

Comment: @Kilisi and if my coworker stabbed another coworker i'd report him to HR right?

Comment: "these cameras might be a prank or something in bad taste" Pretty sure "it's just a prank bro" isn't a legal defense.

Comment: Being "in the porn business" doesn't negate workplace privacy laws.

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken I meant a prank as in there is no camera in the bathroom, just a static picture on a screen and a fake lens in a vent

Comment: @joeqwerty it might be part of a working set, I'm not going to admit any dodgy knowledge but apparently toilet stalls with holes in them are a porn staple.

Comment: There are discussions whether it's OK to omit such short employments: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-it-ok-to-leave-very-short-term-employment-off-my-resume?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BernhardDöbler sure it's ok, doesn't mean it won't be found out. It's a bit of a sensational and public quitting the OP intends

Comment: Excepting that he's on camera and making an enemy is possible, I can't agree with another single statement you've made.  1) It's anyone’s role, just don’t tell sysadmin 2) mgmt. may be complicit or willing to cover up 3) letting others know their rights are violated 4) see #2.  Risk of a 1 week job being found out is VERY low and only if they are interested enough that you’ll probably get to address it anyway.  “little info”:  illegal activity witnessed; “could be removed” = exactly why you DON’T tell the company first;  “unemployment”: OP is unconcerned about unemployment.

Comment: One huge thing that's overlooked: these can't simply be a prank.  Reread the OP's post: they first noticed it when they saw the *camera feed* at the sysadmin's station.  The cameras can't be fake props... while still feeding a signal.

Comment: This is insanely bad advice, both your OP and the comments justifying fit.  Wow.

Comment: This should go in the StackExchange hall of fame as the worst answer ever posted